# onSaveInstanceState() is not gauranted to be called

Tags: android

I have read the below statement from android document

> Because `onSaveInstanceState()` is not guaranteed to be called, you
>   should use it only to record the transient state of the activity (the
>   state of the UI) — you should never use it to store persistent data

Since `onSaveInstanceState()` is not guaranteed to be called. How can we rely on that to save data? is there any particular situation where it won't be called?

Comment: It depends what you want to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use onPause to persist object data.
See this activity life cycle diagram
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Note:  you should still use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().  These are your opportunity to save and restore the state of your application when for example the screen is rotated and the app is killed and then restarted.

Comment: My question is when onSaveInstanceState() wont be called (any specific situation) since onSaveInstanceState() is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: There is an example of when onPause is called but onSaveInstanceState is not called.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 2):

As nPn has already given the link. Read below lines

(Reference :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

> One example of when onPause() and onStop() is called and not this
>   method is when a user  navigates back from activity B to activity A:
>   there is no need to call  onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on B because
>   that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids
>   calling it. An example when onPause() is called and not 
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is when activity B is launched in front of
>   activity A: the  system may avoid calling onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)
>   on activity A if it isn't killed  during the lifetime of B since the
>   state of the user interface of A will stay intact.